# Hibernate mapping many columns to one table

Tags: java, hibernate

How to configure mapping? I want to table "Remittance" were two columns referring to the table "Expense"

Remittance

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REMITTANCE")
public class Remittance implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "REMITTANCE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "remittances", cascade =    CascadeType.ALL)
    private Expense from;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "remittances", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Expense to;
}
```

Expense

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXPENSE")
public class Expense implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EXPENSE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REMITTANCE_ID")
    private Remittance remittances;
}
```

Comment: Make another @ManyToOne `Remittance`, that's your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. I have corrected

Remittance

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REMITTANCE")
public class Remittance implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "REMITTANCE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXPENSE_ID")
    private Expense from;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXPENSE_ID")
    private Expense to;
}
```

Expense

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXPENSE")
public class Expense implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EXPENSE_ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

but now out

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ru.make.alex.web.model.revenue.Remittance column: EXPENSE_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")